# i have chipped my kitchen cabinet door. Is there any way it can be repaired

Tags: kitchens, cabinets

I have chipped the kitchen cabinet door. The laminate is shown in the figure 1 along with the chipped door.

[image]

I am seeking advice for how to repair the chipped door.

Comment: Have you still got the bit chipped off? You could try gluing it back. But it will still be visible...

Comment: There are several ways it could be repaired, but none will be invisible - if you want no sign of a repair, you'll need a new door, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

If you still have the chip and it's in pretty good shape, glue it back in place with some white epoxy from your home store. Use a toothpick to carefully spread the epoxy to fill and smooth out the cracks and seal the edges. If the chip is gone, fill in the hole with the epoxy using a toothpick, being careful not to over fill. Once the epoxy starts to firm up, dab the area with a small paint brush to add some texture. You could use white caulk instead of the epoxy but it will take a lot longer to harden.

Comment: Epoxy or caulk for MDF?

Comment: If the op can match the color I don’t see a problem with silicone or epoxy both should stick to the mdf and the vinyl. If a close color match either would seal it up so it doesn’t swell.